# How to clear the cache in a Titanium WebView?

Tags: android, webview, titanium

#### This is the code for my webview in Titanium (3.4.0):

```
var webView = Ti.UI.createWebView({
        url: pUrl,
        autoDetect: [ Ti.UI.AUTODETECT_NONE ]
});
```

I just need to **clear the cache of this var webView.** I've googled and found a bunch of similar questions but solutions don't actually clear the cache since (as far as I know), there's no built-in function or method for Titanium's WebView to clear it's cache. The reason why I need to clear the cache is I need to clear the username and password of a user's account. *Just for additional information, I'm using this webView in Android.*

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure whether you can clear the cache in titanium easily but maybe you should disable it completely. Have a look at `setCacheMode(cacheMode)` in the [documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.WebView-method-setCacheMode). This method allows you to set the caching mode to one of several predefined modes which are described in the [documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.WebView-property-cacheMode). One of them is `Titanium.UI.Android.WEBVIEW_LOAD_NO_CACHE` which is preventing the webView from caching. Please note that this property only works on Android!

Comment: Hi Robin. I've tried that and it doesn't help clear the cache. I want to clear the cache because I want the user to be prompted of their username and password but that didn't happen. Thanks anyways.

Comment: As I already said I haven't heart of a way to clear the cache. So I tried to solve your problems by suggesting a work around. Good luck anyway.