# How to clear Titanium Webview's cache for iOS devices

Tags: titanium

so I have no problem clearing the Webview's cache for Android devices by simply setting its **cacheMode** property to **Titanium.UI.Android.WEBVIEW_LOAD_NO_CACHE**. Works as expected.

However, after googling for a couple of hours and wading through heaps of older Titanium forum posts I cannot for the life of me find an equivalent setting for iOS devices. I've tried setting the **cache** property to **false** and **autoDetect** to **[Ti.UI.AUTODETECT_NONE]**. I've appended a random number to the end of the URL -- I've even tried one suggestion to modify the SDK's ObjC files directly, but this only cleared cookies and not the webview's cache.

Lastly, I know this can be achieved by reinstalling the app or resetting the simulator's content and settings, but this is simply not an option as the loaded pages are subject to change at any time.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27035866/2439890) to an older question which addresses the same problem (for Android). As far as I know nothing changed since then.

Maybe it helps you to "recycle" your webView object? That is just an idea, I did not tried that myself but if you replace your webView object with a new instance of the webView whenever you want to clear the cache, the cache should be empty. Please only try this if you really need to because it is hacky, produces ugly code and maybe causes performance issues!

Comment: Thanks for the link, Robin. The solution you offered is the exact implementation we're using for Android, which works like a charm. Our biggest hurdle is the ability to clear web view cache in iOS specifically, although the provided answer _appears_ to have resolved the issue.